# Google Functions break when accessing value of body

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to use google functions to work on some post data and return it. While it worked well locally, I cannot get it to work on the google servers.

This 'function':

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  //res.status(200).send({"req.body.message": req.body.message});
  res.status(200).send({"req.body.message.length": req.body.message.length});
  return;
};
```

will fail with this request:

```
fetch("https://us-central1-{myproject}.cloudfunctions.net/demo",
    {
      body: JSON.stringify({"message":"hello"}),
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      mode: "cors"
    }
  ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(d => console.log(d))

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at exports.helloWorld (/user_code/index.js:17:76)
    at ...
```

while the same method with the other res.status... line commented will work AND return {req.body.message: "hello"}

Locally this works.. ANY idea why this would break?

Comment: This function does work for me both locally and deployed. Try printing just `req.body` and you'll know whether the body has proper data or not. Also, you don't need the return statement in the end.

Comment: @noob as mentioned - when I use this line:
res.status(200).send({"req.body.message": req.body.message});
I get the value back as expected. so the data is there and the structure seems correct.

Comment: Looks like you already solved it. I wasn't testing it on the browser though.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was, that I didn't check for the request.method. The browser made the preflight OPTIONS request - and this one failed because there was no req.body.message there. So the real POST request never happened.

This solves it:

```
  exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
      if (req.method === 'POST') {
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false)
        .status(200).send({"req.body.message.length": req.body.message.length });
      }
      else {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false)
        .status(200).send();
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false)
    .status(200).send({"req.body.message": req.body.message.length });
```

Comment: This is exactely what I have now:
    exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false)
        .status(200).send({"req.body.message.length": req.body.message.length });
    };

still the same issue